# how to set object keys to common denominators?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and want every object in the array to have the same keys.

```
var obj1 = {"type": "test", "info": "a lot", "value": 7};
var obj2 = {"value": 5};
var obj3 = {"context": "demo", "info": "very long", "value": 3};
var obj4 = {"info": "no way"};

var dataSet = [obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4];
```

My attempt is to create an array with all possible keys in the first step.
Then loop through that keys array and update the objects if the key was not found.

```
keys.forEach(function(a,b){
  dataSet.forEach(function(c,d){    
    //key not found
    if(a in c === false)
    {
      //add key to object 
      dataSet[b][a] = false;
    }
  });
});
```

Howewer, it does not seem to work correctly.
This is my output:

```
after logic:  [
  {
    "type": false,
    "info": "a lot",
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "value": 5,
    "info": false
  },
  {
    "context": "demo",
    "info": "very long",
    "value": false
  },
  {
    "info": "no way",
    "context": false
  }
]
```

What am I missing there?

```js
var obj1 = {"type": "test", "info": "a lot", "value": 7};
var obj2 = {"value": 5};
var obj3 = {"context": "demo", "info": "very long", "value": 3};
var obj4 = {"info": "no way"};

var dataSet = [obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4];
var keys    = [];

console.log("before logic: ", dataSet);

//Step 1: Fill keys array
dataSet.forEach(function(a,b){  
  Object.keys(a).forEach(function(c,d)
  {
    //add keys to array if not already exists
    if(!keys.includes(c))
    {
      keys.push(c);
    }
  });
});

//Step2: loop through keys array and add key to object if not existing
keys.forEach(function(a,b){
  dataSet.forEach(function(c,d){    
    //key not found
    if(a in c === false)
    {
      //add key to object 
      dataSet[b][a] = false;
    }
  });
});

console.log("after logic: ", dataSet);
```

**EDIT:**

It would be perfect if the keys are always sorted in the same order too.

Comment: You want every object to have every key defaulting to false if not present?

Comment: false is just an option there... could be an empty string too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just collect the keys in a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) using [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), and then assign the missing ones using `forEach()`:

```js
const dataSet = [
  {"type": "test", "info": "a lot", "value": 7},
  {"value": 5},
  {"context": "demo", "info": "very long", "value": 3},
  {"info": "no way"}
];

const keys = new Set(dataSet.flatMap(Object.keys));

dataSet.forEach((v) => keys.forEach((k) => v[k] = k in v ? v[k] : false));

console.log(dataSet);
```

---

To address the additional request of having the keys in the same order, note that historically, JavaScript object properties were unordered, so relying on the order of object properties in JavaScript is almost never a good idea.

That being said, it's hard to get a fixed order when modifying the existing objects, but doable if you create new objects:

```js
const dataSet = [
  {"type": "test", "info": "a lot", "value": 7},
  {"value": 5},
  {"context": "demo", "info": "very long", "value": 3},
  {"info": "no way"}
];

const keys = [...new Set(dataSet.flatMap(Object.keys))];

const result = dataSet.map((v) => keys.reduce((a, k) => ({
  ...a,
  [k]: k in v ? v[k] : false
}), {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: wow... thats way smoother than my attempt. Thank you!
I did not requested it, but is there an option to set all keys to the same order too?

Comment: Historically, JavaScript object properties were unordered, so relying on the order of object properties in JavaScript is almost never a good idea. That being said, it's hard to get a fixed order when modifying the existing objects, but doable if you create new objects.

Comment: @toffler - Picking up on what Robby said: Aside from the fact that there wasn't historically a defined order, the order that *is* defined is complex, so it's generally best to avoid relying on it. If you want order, use an array or a `Map` (`Map`s are ordered in JavaScript: the order is the order the entries were added).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a 'template' object from the `Set` of combined keys and then simply `Object.assign` to this template from each object. This will give you all the properties in a consistent order.

```js
const dataSet = [
  { "type": "test", "info": "a lot", "value": 7 },
  { "value": 5 },
  { "context": "demo", "info": "very long", "value": 3 },
  { "info": "no way" }
];

const template = Object.fromEntries([...new Set(dataSet.flatMap(o => Object.keys(o)))].map(k => [k, false]));

const result = dataSet.map(o => Object.assign({ ...template }, o));

console.log(result)
```

Alternatively you can create the template by simply merging all the objects in the data set and overwriting a default value.

```js
const dataSet = [
  { "type": "test", "info": "a lot", "value": 7 },
  { "value": 5 },
  { "context": "demo", "info": "very long", "value": 3 },
  { "info": "no way" }
];

const template = Object.assign({}, ...dataSet);

for (const k of Object.keys(template)) {
  template[k] = false;
}

const result = dataSet.map(o => Object.assign({ ...template }, o));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is an excellent approach if modifying the existing objects is not a requirement. +1

Comment: Another very smooth answer that works - thank you.
I wonder which of the answers has the best performance?

Comment: @toffler A lot depends on whether you need to modify the existing objects, or are OK to create copies. As far as performance goes, a very verbose approach using simple loops will probably be fastest, but it only becomes relevant for very large lists.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen It does not really matter if the original is modified or a copy is created.

Comment: agreed, a very quick test puts my last `Object.assign` based answer far ahead on chrome, but as @RobbyCornelissen noted it depends on your specific needs. It creates the fewest intermediate objects, and Set isn't very efficient in my limited testing experience.

Comment: It's a shame that I can only accept 1 answer, since this one is perfect too.
Thank you all for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is basically a typo: You're using the wrong index when you set the key:

```
dataSet[b][a] = false;
```

`b` is the index of the **key** in `keys`, not the index of the object in `dataSet`. You don't need to do that indexing at all, just do:

```
c[a] = false;
```

It's ***much*** easier to follow what you're doing and such when you use meaningful names for variables rather than `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`. Here's your code with some reasonable renaming and with the change described above:

```js
var obj1 = { type: "test", info: "a lot", value: 7 };
var obj2 = { value: 5 };
var obj3 = { context: "demo", info: "very long", value: 3 };
var obj4 = { info: "no way" };

var dataSet = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4];
var keys = [];

console.log("before logic: ", JSON.stringify(dataSet, null, 4));

//Step 1: Fill keys array
dataSet.forEach(function (obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    //add keys to array if not already exists
    if (!keys.includes(key)) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
  });
});

//Step2: loop through keys array and add key to object if not existing
keys.forEach(function (key) {
  dataSet.forEach(function (obj) {
    //key not found
    if (key in obj === false) {
      //add key to object
      obj[key] = false;
    }
  });
});

console.log("after logic: ", JSON.stringify(dataSet, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

But that code can be much simpler using a `Set` and modern language features:

```js
const obj1 = { type: "test", info: "a lot", value: 7 };
const obj2 = { value: 5 };
const obj3 = { context: "demo", info: "very long", value: 3 };
const obj4 = { info: "no way" };

const dataSet = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4];
const keys = new Set(); // *** Use a set

console.log("before logic: ", dataSet);

// Step 1: Fill keys array
for (const obj of dataSet) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        keys.add(key);
    }
}

// Step2: loop through keys array and add key to object if not existing
for (const key of keys) {
    for (const obj of dataSet) {
        if (!(key in obj)) {
            obj[key] = false;
        }
    }
}

console.log("after logic: ", JSON.stringify(dataSet, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

[Robby Cornelissen takes it much further](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72182694/157247), but I wanted to show using simple loops.

Comment: I almost feel stupid now, was searching for my mistake for ages :D - perfect lesson why meaningful names are important - thank's a lot!